# Is there a way to figure out which line of a logfile is being read by logstash

Tags: logstash

I recently experienced a heap size memory error and because on the same machine i'm also running logstash, logstash was also not workign anymore. Then I increased heap size but logstash is not continuing to process data where it ended. How can I figure out what logstash is doing currently? For instance a command giving the current line of a file or similar. Where could be information where it stopped processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html):
Basically the input file plugin should create a sincedb file that should store the below information:

> Sincedb files are text files with four columns:
>
> - The inode number (or equivalent).
> - The major device number of the file system (or equivalent).
> - The minor device number of the file system (or equivalent).
> - The current byte offset within the file.